# How to find locked pdf

Tags: pdf, find

Is there a way to find locked pdf inside a directory structure using the command line (or any other tool)? In other words, how to amend this code to obtain the desired result in unix? (in my case x64/LM 19.3)

```
$find . -name *pdf
```

Comment: Its good when askers show their research effort. These two sub-problems come to mind: (1) testing if a given *single* PDF is locked, (2) using arbitrary command as a test in `find`. // During your research did you manage to solve any of the two (at least partially)?

Comment: I think if I knew how to test if a single pdf is locked, I could figure out the rest.